# How to read the File from the FTP server

Tags: magento2

As I have to read the File From the FTP server of the last modified file from the particular path

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

ini_set("memory_limit", -1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
require "../app/bootstrap.php";

// Set a config array of information related to your Magento 2 installation
$config = [
    'bootstrap_path' => '../app/bootstrap.php',
    'store' => '0',
    'theme' => "VendoreThemeName/ThemeName",
];

$_SERVER[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
    DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
    DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
    DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
    DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
];

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $config['store'] ?? 'default'; // Website code as same in admin panel

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');

$ftp_server = 'FTP HOST NAME';
$ftp_user_name = 'FTP USER NAME';
$ftp_user_pass = 'FTP PASSWORD';

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// get all file

$file_list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '/'); // add here file path

//add your logic here
```

To check last modify date time [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_filemtime.asp)

Comment: Through the FTP I have to check in the Particular folder to last modified file with the use of magento2

Comment: $file_list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '/');
This function retrieve the only root folder from the FTP I have to retrieve the last modified file from the specific folder
            $folder= 'Folder name;
    $ files = $this->ftp->ls($open, $folder);
It is not retrive the specific folder

Comment: add your path in $file_list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, 'YOUR PATH');

Comment: Throwing this error in Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for while checked the last modified file